# How to add transition delay to a GIF?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using `import 'package:image/image.dart' as imgs;` this package

I can perfectly create a GIF but i cannot set the delay transition for every frame, Here's my code:

```
 List<int>? generateGIF(Iterable<imgs.Image> images) {
    final imgs.Animation animation = imgs.Animation();
    for (imgs.Image image in images) {
      animation.addFrame(image);
    }
    return imgs.encodeGifAnimation(animation);
  }
```

My question is, how to put a delay for each frame?.
for example, 1000 milliseconds to each frame transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
List<int>? generateGIF(Iterable<imgs.Image> images) {
final imgs.Animation animation = imgs.Animation();
for (imgs.Image image in images) {
  image.duration = 1;
  animation.addFrame(image);
}
return imgs.encodeGifAnimation(animation);
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).